# Vue 3.3.4 : Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'user')

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs3

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'user')
    at ReactiveEffect.fn (Show.vue:101:46)
    at ReactiveEffect.run (reactivity.esm-bundler.js:178:19)
    at get value [as value] (reactivity.esm-bundler.js:1147:33)
    at unref (reactivity.esm-bundler.js:1026:29)
    at Object.get (reactivity.esm-bundler.js:1032:35)
    at Proxy._sfc_render (Show.vue:69:30)
    at renderComponentRoot (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:816:16)
    at ReactiveEffect.componentUpdateFn [as fn] (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5701:46)
    at ReactiveEffect.run (reactivity.esm-bundler.js:178:19)
    at instance.update (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5814:51)
```

I already tried to

1. Check the data source: Ensure that the data source containing the **`user`** property is properly defined and accessible. Verify that the data is being fetched correctly and assigned to the object.
2. Verify the object structure: Make sure that the object containing the **`user`** property is correctly structured. Ensure that it has a **`user`** property defined and that it is not null or undefined.
3. Handle asynchronous operations: If the **`user`** property is being retrieved asynchronously, such as from an API call or asynchronous function, make sure to handle the asynchronous operation properly. Use async/await or promises to ensure that the **`user`** property is resolved before accessing it.
4. Check component lifecycle: Confirm that you are accessing the **`user`** property at the appropriate time in the component lifecycle. For example, if you are accessing it in the **`created`** or **`mounted`** lifecycle hooks, ensure that the data has been fetched and assigned before accessing it.
5. Use conditional rendering: To avoid accessing the **`user`** property when it is undefined, consider using conditional rendering in your template. You can use **`v-if`** or **`v-show`** directives to conditionally render the component or its contents based on the availability of the **`user`** property.

but still did not work

## This is show.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="flex flex-col-reverse md:grid md:grid-cols-12 gap-4">
        <Box class="md:col-span-7 flex items-center">
            <div v-if="listing.images.length" class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-1">
                <img
                    v-for="image in listing.images" :key="image.id"
                    :src="image.src"
                />
            </div>
            <div v-else class="w-full text-center font-medium text-gray-500">No images</div>
        </Box>
        <div class="md:col-span-5 flex flex-col gap-4">
            <Box>
                <template #header>
                    Basic info
                </template>
                <Price :price="listing.price" class="text-2xl font-bold" />
                <ListingSpace :listing="listing" class="text-lg" />
                <ListingAddress :listing="listing" class="text-gray-500" />
            </Box>

            <Box>
                <template #header>
                    Monthly Payment
                </template>
                <div>
                    <label class="label">Interest rate ({{ interestRate }}%)</label>
                    <input
                        v-model.number="interestRate"
                        type="range" min="0.1" max="30" step="0.1"
                        class="w-full h-4 bg-gray-200 rounded-lg appearance-none cursor-pointer dark:bg-gray-700"
                    />

                    <label class="label">Duration ({{ duration }} years)</label>
                    <input
                        v-model.number="duration"
                        type="range" min="3" max="35" step="1"
                        class="w-full h-4 bg-gray-200 rounded-lg appearance-none cursor-pointer dark:bg-gray-700"
                    />

                    <div class="text-gray-600 dark:text-gray-300 mt-2">
                        <div class="text-gray-400">Your monthly payment</div>
                        <Price :price="monthlyPayment" class="text-3xl" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="mt-2 text-gray-500">
                        <div class="flex justify-between">
                            <div>Total paid</div>
                            <div>
                                <Price :price="totalPaid" class="font-medium" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="flex justify-between">
                            <div>Principal paid</div>
                            <div>
                                <Price :price="listing.price" class="font-medium" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="flex justify-between">
                            <div>Interest paid</div>
                            <div>
                                <Price :price="totalInterest" class="font-medium" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </Box>

            <MakeOffer v-if="user" :listing-id="listing.id" :price="listing.price"
            />
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>

import ListingAddress from '@/Components/ListingAddress.vue'
import ListingSpace from "@/Components/UI/ListingSpace.vue";
import Price from '@/Components/Price.vue'
import Box from '@/Components/UI/Box.vue'
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { useMonthlyPayment } from '@/Composables/useMonthlyPayment'
import { usePage } from '@inertiajs/vue3'
import { computed } from 'vue'
import MakeOffer from "@/Pages/Listing/Show/Components/MakeOffer.vue";



const interestRate = ref(2.5)
const duration = ref(25)

const props = defineProps({
    listing: Object,
})

const { monthlyPayment, totalPaid, totalInterest } = useMonthlyPayment(
    props.listing.price, interestRate, duration,
)

const page = usePage()
const user = computed(() => page.props.value.user);
</script>
```